# a sql code or function to remove all the special characters from a particular column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

a sql code or function to remove all the special characters from a particular column in a table.

:a oracle code to remove all the special character from a column .for example ABC D.E.F so it should be ABC DEF,space should be maintained between 2 words.

Comment: What is your question again? What characters are included in the set of "special characters"?

Comment: @Mwiesner :a oracle code to remove all the special character from a column .for example ABC D.E.F so it should be ABC DEF,space should be maintained between 2 words.

Comment: Define special character. State RDBMS you're working on.

Comment: @Rene: it can be like ABC - D.E.F,i am working on oracle sql

Comment: @sonaa Please add this information to your post. You can edit it by clicking the 'edit' link.

Comment: Ok Miracle ,i will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the hyphens and the dots, you can go with `translate` like so:

```
select
   translate(column_name, 'Q._"?!@#$%^&*æ', 'Q')
from
   your_table;
```

Comment: it has not removed . dot

Comment: I have changed the code so as to remove the dot as well.

Comment: thanks Rene,it is working now but suppose if we have two words separated by space ,lets take an example ABC D.E.F ,the output should be like ABC DEF ,so this part of code will work in that case.rite??

Comment: I need to remove all the special character like Ã,._"?!@#$%^&*æ'

Comment: You still fail to define what makes a character special.

Comment: In my work i need to remove this particular symbols ._"?!@#$%^&*æ' -

Comment: In that case you want to use `translate(column_name, 'Q._"?!@#$%^&*æ', 'Q')`, see my changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be a Regular Expression, this removes anything but spaces and letters a to z:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[^a-z ]','' , 1, 0, 'i')
```

Comment: Hi ,this is not working for me,can you please provide some other solution.

Comment: @sonaa: **not working** is not really detailed information.  **What** is not working? Wrong result? Error message?